# Postal code and date data preparation

Tags: python

I would like to find out by means of ML whether insurance damages have a connection.
For this I have dates such as time when the damage has occurred and postal code.

How can I use these to apply Machine Learning to them?

Comment: With the post code, you should look for data sets that include statistics by post code (such as crime stats, affluence levels etc). Companies like Experion often sell these data and government stats like a census might have something. If you decide to use geographic coordinates, remember that longitude effectively changes units as latitude changes so better to use a country specific system such as eastings and northings in the UK.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated Donald Duck. It is usually a good practice if you do some research and try apply concepts yourself before ask question.

Comment: `python` does not look like a relevant tag for your question. Consider updating.

Comment: Nein? ich möchte Ja mit Python den Datensatz programmieren aber danke für die Unfreundliche Hilfe

No? i want to program the dataset with Python but thank you for the unfriendly help

Answer (score 1):

You have to transform your data so that if two data points are close to each other they are more likely to be related.

- Your times you can for instance convert to seconds from 1. Januar 1970, 00:00 (Unix time)
- The postal code is most likely already in a way that two postal codes that are close to each other numerically are also close to each other geographically. If this is not the case for your country you might be better off with converting the postal codes to geographic coordinates.

These two features will then have different magnitudes so don't forget to normalize them before training a classifier.

Comment: I have now merged the postal code with the address and used it to create a geocode thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on how you prepare the data. It would be very valuable if you use some external data with respect to postal code as suggested by @Dan. For example you can try to build a simple regression model that tries to predict number of damage claims. For this, inputs may be population, average income, month of the year, number of insurance holders in that area and output may be number of insurance claimed. You've to be bit creative and inquisitive, and experiment with different features/models to arrive the model that suits your need. All the best.

Comment: I have now merged the postal code with the address and used it to create a geocode thank you very much for your help :)